# Text is not respecting <p> in Chrome and FF

Tags: css, html

So I have here a div with p tag inside and text inside p tag. The problem is, the text is not respecting the p tag. It wont break although I put break-word in the css.

`comgtech.com/partners.php`

HTML:

```
<table style="border:1px solid red;height:300px; display:inline-block; position:relative; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; width:805px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="box">
                    <a href="http://www.bayadcenter.com" target="_blank">
                        <img src="images/bayadcenter-logo.png" style="z-index:3; margin-top:5px; text-align:center;"/>
                    </a>
                    <p style="text-align:justify; width:260px; font-size:10px; color:#514f4d;word-wrap:break-word; height:200px;">
                    <!--p style="margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px; z-index:3; text-align:justify;font-size:10px;" -->
                        <span style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">Herradura Resources Corporation</span><br />
                        Herradura Resources Corporation (HRC) was established with the primary purpose of developing a LOAD ADVANCE facility with the objective to provide a more convenient, secure, and cost-efficient way of granting benefits to employees and agents. <br /> <br />
                        The Load Advance or &#34;BALE&#34; system aims to add variation to the existing benefits being offered to employees by providing them Value Added Services (VAS) particularly airtime load transfer services. This solution is considered to be the first and only BALE-VAS in the Philippines.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
border:1px solid #cccccc;
width:260px;
height:290px;
padding-bottom:0.5em;
overflow:hidden; 
z-index:2;

    -moz-box-shadow 3px 5px 4px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 5px 4px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 4px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);


    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#060606')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#060606');

}
```

Works fine in IE.

Edited:
It looks like this:

```
--table------------------------------------------------------
|                                                           |
|  __<p>______________                                      |
| |                   |                                     |
| | texttexttextextextextextextextextextextextextextextextex|
| |                   |                                     |
| |                   |                                     |
| |___________________|                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: [jsFiddle of the given code](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/QgCmP/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply [add the style `white-space: normal;` to the `p`](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/sgSJa/).

You have set [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on the parent `table` element, and the `p` inherited that. `white-space: normal` undoes that style.

Answer (score 0):

You have to only use this:

```css
word-break:normal;
```

Put it in your `<p>` and words will break. For example:

```html
<p style="text-align:justify; width:260px; font-size:10px; color:#514f4d;word-wrap:break-word; height:200px;word-break:normal">
```